# Scattered declaration of class/instance variable names in Python due to combining declaration with useage

Tags: python

I'm very new to python so please don't be displeased if I missed some thing.

It seems that class and instance variables in python simply sprint into existence when they are used, this combination of use and declaration of instance variables results in the declaration of a class no longer being the only place that a class's data structures can be defined. consequently given a class `Cls` one cannot tell what data structures been created for it for one to access simply by tracing up stream to the class's declaration, as one can do with languages such as C and Java. Instead, one is compel to search all modules that might have used/define variables for that class.

As a result when a class is used by multiple modules, although you know of some data structure belong to that class must have been defined, to know it's name and type, you have to search through all the imported files that might have used that class (in a way that create new variables) to see just where was it used/defined.

example
declaration:

```
    class Cls:
         pass
```

module1:

```
    Cls.m = 2.3
```

module_n:

```
    print Cls.m
```

And again the issue being for those who operate on `module_n`, before they write that print statement, they don't know whether the variable name will be defined in `module1` or some other module in the import list that could have used `Cls` , but if they can't find where the variable's defined they can't use it, since they don't know the name of that variable, or even its existence.

As someone less than a day into Python who is reading a rather lengthy project, I want to know if there's any trick to solve this, both as a reader and as the writer, how can such headaches be avoided

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear but I think I understand. I would also recommend rereading the question you posted and re-wording it. It sounds like your question is "because of Python's flexibility and the ability to add variables to the class or instance itself, it might be hard to find where those variables are created." But unfortunately, there is no trick to it. I would just recommend avoid doing that (Cls.m = 3) outside of the class if possible. It's just one of the tradeoffs of having a language like Python.

Comment: Echoing @dtc, note that Javascript has this problem in spades.

Comment: @dtc: thanks for the feedback,  I tried my best in rewording, and it's a pity there's no trick, hopefully there exists a good IDE to do the job